# Android Studio AutoFormat Plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, autoformat

Is there any plugin to autoformat code like this?

```
myObject.methodName               = "foo";
myObject.longMethodName           = "foo";
myObject.evenLongerMethodName     = "foo";
myObject.theLongestMethodName1234 = "foo";
```

Equal sign in the same column in clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to play with this settings:

[image: Settings]